# Why every endoser peer run a ccenv container with nodejs chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

We know the chaincode is installed on every endoser peer, and only instantiated on one endoser peer.

```
1, so other peer will copy dev* image of chaincode and run it when needed?
```

Also, I found, when using composer to deploy/upgrade the chaincode, every endoser peer will run a ccenv docker container,

```
2, just the ccenv to build the chaincode, why not just use one peer to build the image and copy to other peer?
3, the ccenv build the chaincode, will be included in install step or the instantiate step for more clear instruction?
```

because i found too many ccenv run at the same time, often fails with one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabric is a distributed system and therefore the expectation is that Peers are run as independent components not on the same machine in the same docker network for example (this will not be a valid deployment scenario, only a development scenario). This is why each peer needs to build and run it's instance of a chaincode container, you can't have one peer build the chaincode as the other peers being in their own environment will have no access to it

Hyperledger Composer will send instantiate requests to all peers on the channel so all those peers at instantiate time will build a version of the chaincode so it can run the instantiate transaction simulation.

ccenv is the container image that has the required components in order to build chaincode, it is not used to run chaincode.

Comment: I got the usage of ccenv.
So how to understant this "the chaincode is instantiated only once in one channel."
1,In composer situation, does it means the chaincode instantiated many times in one channel?
2,The chaincode is instantiated only once in one channel on a peer, what will happen when the other peer try to run the dev* chaincode docker?
It just copys the chaincode docker from the instantiated, and rename it?

Comment: You seem to be confusing instantiation with the process of a peer being able to endorse a transaction simulation. These are not the same things. instantiation is the binding of a chaincode to the channel (ie stating that the channel will use this chaincode package at the specified version). It is only done once. The process of instantiation requires the running of a transaction simulation.
For a peer to endorse a transaction it must have that version of the chaincode running, so it creates the chaincode image and starts the chaincode

Comment: With composer it sends a txn during instantiation to every peer on the channel, so each peer needs to simulate that transaction so must build and start a chaincode container of the version defined as part of instantiation to perform txn simulation.
This is expected behaviour in composer and cannot be changed. 
If you want more control then you should not use composer. In fact you really should get off of composer now anyway

Comment: Thanks,yes i was a little confused by the upgrade command in composer. Now i am trying to get off of composer after it was deprecated.

Comment: can't remember if I pointed you to this, but if not you may find this helpful for porting from composer
https://davidkel.github.io/docs/Porting/TOC.html

Comment: Yes，you have reminded me of that. I was a little disappointed about the deprecation of composer.It will save us a lot with many convenient capabilities.